# Approximation problem using molifiers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I was solving a different problem, which will be solved if the following convergence result is true:

Suppose $\Omega\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain. Suppose $f\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$. Does there exist a sequence $f_n\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega))$(i.e., smooth function with compact support in $\Omega$.) such that,

\begin{equation*}
1) f_n \rightarrow f, \,\text{pointwise at each point of}\, \Omega.\\
2)\partial_jf_n\rightarrow  \partial_jf \,\text{pointwise at each point of}\, \Omega.\\
3)|f_n|<C\,(C\,\text{is a constant independent of }n, \forall(n\in\mathbb{N}).\\
4)|\partial_jf_n|< D \,(D\,\text{is a constant independent of }n, \forall(n\in\mathbb{N}).
\end{equation*}

Above $\partial _j$ denotes the partial derivatives wrt $j$.

I am quite certain that 1) and 3) should hold by the property of the Molifiers. Not quite certain about 2) and 4).

[**Defintion**: $f\in$ $C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ means all the partial derivatives of all orders of $f$ have a continuous extension in a neighbourhood of the boundary.]

Comment: How do you define $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$?

Comment: @PhoemueX I have written the definition now. Please check! I think $C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ is a over kill. I think we only need the boundedness of the function and its partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Unless $f$ is compactly supported, (4) does not hold. Let $\Omega = [0,1]$, and let $f(x) = 1$. For any compactly supported function, $f_n(0) = 0$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(1/m) = 1$, so by the mean value theorem there exists points $c_{n,m}$ such that $$|f'_n(c_{n,m})| \geq \frac{1}{2m}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Problems arise from the fact that you are requiring $f_n\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ instead of $f_n\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$.

If you definitely require that $f_n\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ then the best you can do is (1), (2), and (3) as demonstrated by 1mdlrjcmed's counter-example. The issue is that, if the original function $f$ is bounded away from zero (for example, $f \geqslant 1$ in $\Omega$), then, as $n\to +\infty$, $f_n$ is approaching $f$ in a pointwise sense, but $f_n$ has to jump from $0$ at the boundary to above $1$ which forces the gradient of $f_n$ to blow-up. This intuition is made rigorous in 1mdlrjcmed's counter-example.

For (1), (2), and (3), you can do this using mollifiers, as you mention:

Let $\eta\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ be given by $$ \eta(x) = \begin{cases}
Ce^{-\frac 1{1-x^2}} , & \text{if } \vert x \vert <1\\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$ where $C>0$ is such that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\eta=1$. Now let $\eta_\varepsilon (x) = \frac 1{\varepsilon^n} \eta(x/\varepsilon)$ and $g^\varepsilon = g \ast \eta_\varepsilon$. It is well known that $\overline{\operatorname{supp} g^\varepsilon} \subset \{x+y\in \mathbb R^n \text{ s.t. } x\in \overline{\operatorname{supp} g} , \vert y \vert \leqslant \varepsilon\}$ i.e the support of $g^\varepsilon$ can be "a little bigger" than the support of $g$.

To construct your $f_n\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ satisfying (1), (2), and (3), let $\varphi_n \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ such that $0\leqslant \varphi_n\leqslant 1$, $\varphi_n =1$ in $\{ x\in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)>4/n\}$, and $\varphi_n =0$ in $\{ x\in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)<2/n\}$. Then let $f_n := (f\varphi_n) \ast \eta_{1/n}$. This is a sequence of smooth functions whose support is in $\Omega$ (due to the inclusion of $\varphi_n$). Moreover, by the properties of mollifier, it converges to $f$ in $C^\infty_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$, which, in particular, implies (1) and (2). For (3), we have that $$\vert f_n(x) \vert \leqslant \int_{\mathbb R^n} \vert f(x-y)\vert \varphi_n(x-y)\eta_{1/n}(y) \, d y \leqslant \| f\|_{L^\infty(B_R)} $$ for some large ball $B_R$ such that $\Omega \subset \subset B_R$.

If you are happy to allow $f_n \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ then you can simply take $f_n = f \ast \eta_{1/n}$ since, in this case, $f_n \to f$ in $C^\infty_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ which implies (1)-(4).